# split two list of equal length and do separate calculation

Tags: r

I have two lists

```
list1 <- list(4,6,7,9, 9,12,14,12)
list2 <- list(7,8,9,10,14,13,12,11)
```

I need to do separate calculation on every 2 elements on each list. ie. add the first two elements between the two lists, next two subtract, followed by multiply next two, and divide last two in the order `list1[1:2]+list2[1:2], list1[3:4]-list2[3:4], list1[5:6]*list2[5:6], list1[7:8]/list2[7:8]` (it gives error).  Expected output is

```
result <- list(11, 14, -2, -1, 126, 156, 1.16, 1.09)
```

Comment: Make your lists vectors: `v1 <- unlist(list1)` and work with those.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that uses `paste` to create the expression and then `sapply` to evaluate these (`lapply` can be used as well if the result should be a list).

```
list3 <- rep(c("+","-","*","/"), each=2)
sapply(paste(list1, list3, list2), function(x){ eval(parse(text=x)) })
```

Results in:

```
     4 + 7      6 + 8      7 - 9     9 - 10     9 * 14    12 * 13    14 / 12    12 / 11
 11.000000  14.000000  -2.000000  -1.000000 126.000000 156.000000   1.166667   1.090909
```